# How can I prevent XAML VisualStates from interfering with Windows UI Composition animation?

Tags: uwp, composition, winui

I believe the Windows.UI.Composition tools are conflicting with the XAML VisualStates on buttons.

GIF #1 When a button is in its Normal state, without the cursor hovering, the animations work and the buttons disappear successfully on scrolling down and then reappear successfully on scrolling up.

GIF #2 If the cursor is hovering over a button when the composition animation completes, and the mouse exits the button before scrolling up, I believe the PointerOver state gets frozen and the opacity of 0% gets stuck. The only way to fix it is to hover again to unjam the XAML VisualStates.

[image: Buttons can disappear and reappear.]
[image: Buttons disappear and do not reappear until PointerOver event]

The buttons are all in the same StackPanel, which is the target of the opacity animation. When one button has this problem, the whole StackPanel gets stuck at 0% opacity. The code below is the general gist, some pieces omitted for brevity. I do not think this is a code issue, I think it is a platform limitation and I am looking for a workaround.

```
CompositionPropertySet _scrollerPropertySet = 
ElementCompositionPreview.GetScrollViewerManipulationPropertySet((ScrollViewer)sender);
Compositor _compositor = _scrollerPropertySet.Compositor;
CompositionPropertySet _props = _compositor.CreatePropertySet();
_props.InsertScalar("progress", 0);
var scrollingProperties = 
_scrollerPropertySet.GetSpecializedReference<ManipulationPropertySetReferenceNode>();
var props = _props.GetReference();
var progressNode = props.GetScalarProperty("progress");
ExpressionNode progressAnimation = EF.Clamp(-scrollingProperties.Translation.Y / clampSizeNode, 0, 1);
_props.StartAnimation("progress", progressAnimation);

// StackPanel relevant code:

Visual carOperationButtonStackPanelVisual= 
ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(CarOperationStackPanel);
ExpressionNode carSubtitleObjectOpacityAnimation = 1 - (progressNode * 2);
carOperationButtonStackPanelVisual.StartAnimation("Opacity", carSubtitleObjectOpacityAnimation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code excerpt above, near the end, this line

```
ExpressionNode carSubtitleObjectOpacityAnimation = 1 - (progressNode * 2);
```

should be

```
ExpressionNode carSubtitleObjectOpacityAnimation = ExpressionFunctions.Lerp(0, 1, 1 - (progressNode * 2));
```

This will force the opacity to update with a linear interpolation from 0 to 1. For what it's worth, I copied the source code from the [Win UI samples repo](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples/blob/master/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2014393/ShyHeader/ShyHeader.xaml.cs), which does not use Lerp() for opacity. My conclusion is that Lerp is more taxing on the system, but necessary when the controls have visual states. The sample repo animates a simple TextBlock (which does not have visual states).